# If there is a way to achieve this kind of result below using group_concat

Tags: mysql, group-concat

Data

```
Brcode  name
1.      A
2.      A
3.      A
```

Expected result

```
Brcode  Name Common
1        A             1,2,3
2        A              1,2,3
3        A              1,2,3
```

Comment: maybe subselect ?

Comment: Sorry im just new here. I've already upvote and mark as accepted your answer. It really works. Thank you so much sir. God bless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do a join.

```
CREATE TABLE test_tbl        (
             Brcode int(9),
              name varchar(3) );


    INSERT INTO test_tbl VALUES (1,'A'),
                                (2,'A'),
                                (3,'A');
    

SELECT t1.Brcode,
       t1.name,
       t2.common
FROM test_tbl t1       
inner join 
(
  select name ,group_concat(Brcode  SEPARATOR ',') as Common from test_tbl group by name
) as t2 on t1.name=t2.name;
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7yUJcuMJPncBBnrExKbzYz/99

Result:
[image]